# Api.ai Detect Chat User Information

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there any way in which Chat User information can be identified like user name, logged-in ids etc. in Slack or Skype integration with Api.ai.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now implemented only for Slack service. You could use context `generic` and its parameters `slack_user_id` and `slack_channel`.

For another services you have to implement your own processing using api.ai open source bots.